# how to remove unwanted files from maven project

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, version-control

I am currently working with a spring web project. In my project, i am using git,maven and eclipse as IDE. when viewing git status in terminal these three files are present in all cases:

- .classpath
- .gitignore
- .settings

how can in remove these unwanted files. i have no idea how these present in my project. my colleagues have also experiencing this issue.

any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its a git repository, you can include below lines in your `.gitignore` file and then commit your `.gitignore` file to your central git repository, after that your local git repository won't show the ignore files which you added.

```
.settings
.classpath
```

Read more about .gitignore here https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/.

Edit :- You these files are already unchecked then you need to run below command (**If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal**:) :-

```
git rm --cached FILENAME
```

So in you case above command will look like `git rm --cached .classpath` and `git rm --cached .settings`.

Answer (score 1):

Create [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in your project root directory and specify file path you want to untrack, for example:

```
.classpath
.project
.settings
target/
.mvn/
```

Answer (score 0):

In SVN Repository can use Add to `svn:ignore`. using this one can remove unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

As other guys mentioned - you should add `.gitignore` file to the root of the project. There is a good Github project - [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore). You could concat this files into one:

1. [Java.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore)
2. [Maven.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Maven.gitignore)
3. [Eclipse.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore)

You could read more about `.gitignore` in a project [description](https://github.com/github/gitignore#a-collection-of-gitignore-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly open your workspace and open your project, after that you can manually delete those files... Make sure you check "show hidden files" if you are using windows and before deleting please close eclipse and then remove the files.